# Solving a Cartesian and parametric equation at a intersection.

Tags: trigonometry, parametric

A curve C has parametric equations:

$x=4cos(2t)$ and $y=3sin(t)$ $-\frac{\pi}{2} < t < \frac{\pi}{2}$

The normal of a point A$(2,1.5)$ on curve C has the equation $6y-16x+23=0$

The curve and the normal intersect again at point B. What is the Y and X values at point B?

I think that at point B, the x and y values of the normal and the curve C are identical and hence I tried to substitute the parametric equations into the normal equation in a attempt to determine T, which would allow me to find the X and Y values.

However, after subsitiution, I got $18sin(t) -64cos(2t) +23 = 0$

I don't know how to solve this and it feels like i'm not on the right path.
Can somebody clarify as to the best way to approach this problem?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path.  If you solve that trigonometric equation for $t$, that will give you the **values** (plural) of the parameter for which the normal line intersects the parametric curve.  The Cartesian coordinates then correspond to plugging in that value of $t$ into the parametric equations.

So to get you started, write $$\begin{align*}  0 &= 18 \sin t - 64 \cos 2t + 23 \\ &= 18 \sin t - 64 (1 - 2\sin^2 t) + 23 \\ &= 128 \sin^2 t + 18 \sin t - 41. \end{align*}$$  Then let $u = \sin t$ and solve the resulting quadratic in $u$; then take the inverse sine to recover $t$.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the following.

You proceeded OK, and it rests to solve the equality $18\sin t  - 64\cos 2t +23 = 0$. Do it.  We have $\cos 2t=1- 2\sin^2 t$. So

$18\sin t  - 64(1- 2\sin^2 t) +23 = 0$

$128\sin^2 t+18\sin t  - 41 = 0$

$\sin t=\frac{-9\pm 73}{128}$

$\sin t_1=\frac{1}{2}$ - this is for the first intersection point

$\sin t_2=\frac{-41}{64}$

$\cos 2t_2=1- 2\sin^2 t_2=\frac{367}{2048}$ - this is for second intersection point

Then $B=(4\cos 2t_2, 3\sin t_2)=\left(\frac{367}{512},\frac{-123}{64}\right)$.